# Codeigniter: 404 on existing controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

When I set `$route['default_controller']` to 'blog', CI opens my controller without problems. When I want to access it via URL, CI returns a 404.

My controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Saved at

> application/controllers/Blog.php

Some other config things:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'blog';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

URL I try to use:

> http://localhost:63342/project/public_html/blog/

.htaccess to hide index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

How can I fix this issue? I tried a lot of solutions from similar questions without success

Comment: Remove that slash in front of the index.php in your RewriteRule ... it's redirecting to your webroot.

Comment: @Narf Same result as before :/

Comment: Yes, I suspected that alone wouldn't solve your problem, which is why I only left it as a comment ... But that surely is a part of the issue. Either way, it's nothing to do with CodeIgniter; you only need to tackle .htaccess and/or your Apache configuration.

Comment: Alright. I tried it without .htaccess too by using http://localhost:63342/project/public_html/index.php/blog/ which also gave me a 404

Comment: try to add `die("I am here");` in your `index` function and check.

Comment: @urfusion I've added an echo, which I'd see when the index method would've been called, but it did not :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is in `project` folder in main directory of the local server, change your address to:

```
http://localhost:63342/project/blog
```

You configured that page as your default controller, so it should work even by:

```
http://localhost:63342/project
```

Comment: My index.php lies in project/public_html, so the address is correct. As mentioned in my question [When I set $route['default_controller'] to 'blog', CI opens my controller without problems.] it work's when I open http://localhost:63342/project/public_html/, but not on direct URL call

Comment: Your project should be in the main folder(root) of the website not public_html. If you using xampp as your local web server your project(which contains files like application index and htaccess) should be in: xampp/htdocs/project/